# Form submission doesn't work - PHP

Tags: php, html, validation

I'm working on a form validation and I'm currently doing some debugging on my code. I'll insert the necessary code snippets below:

Form code:

```
echo '<h1> Seismic Recording </h1>
<div>
<form action="validate2.php" method="POST">';

echo "Latitude: <input type='text' name='latitude'>";
echo "Longitude: <input type='text' name='longitude'required>";
echo 'Wave Type: <select id="wave_type" name="wave_type" required>
        <option selected value="s">S</option>
        <option value="p">P</option>
        <option value="surface_wave">Surface Wave</option>
        </select>';
echo "Wave Value: <input type='text' name='wave_value' required>";
echo 'Upload CSV File: <input type="file" name="file">';
echo " <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>
</div> ";
```

Validation code:

```
echo "w";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "t";
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    if ($latitude  == NULL) {
        echo "Please insert a latitude . <br>";
        $error = $error + 1;
    }
}

echo "q";
```

The form validations that I've put within the if statement doesn't work. I tried debugging the code by inserting the 'echo "q"' and  'echo "w"' to see where the problem lies. Those statements work (they output the characters). But the  'echo "t"' within the if statement doesn't work. Why is that so?

Result of var_dump($_POST):

> array(5) { ["latitude"]=> string(0) "" ["longitude"]=> string(1) "g"
>   ["wave_type"]=> string(1) "s" ["wave_value"]=> string(1) "g"
>   ["file"]=> string(0) "" }

My issue isn't so much in getting the latitude to validate but why doesn't the 'echo t' work?

Comment: Stick `print_r($_POST)` in your code to help troubleshoot

Comment: Do use valid HTML in the first place. `<input />` `<form></form>` :)

Comment: show your full html code, r u using </form>??? because as per your debugging, `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` this not working.

Comment: And: What did you enter into the form on your test? Because if `$_POST['submit']` was set, then maybe `$_POST['latitude']` is stil empty

Comment: `$latitude` can never be equal to `NULL`, instead use this `if` condition: `if(!isset($latitude) || empty($latitude)){ ...`

Comment: Show your real code not the half pasted stuff here, show your test data, show dump of request ;) What should we guess from that, what you have pasted??

Comment: If this is a legacy project, good luck, else, I recommend using a framework. Why work so hard? http://webdeveloper.gdemolished.com/stop-building-shitty-php-web-applications/

Comment: @jszobody I did that. It shows latitude as being empty. But my question is apart from the latitude, why doesn't the 'echo "t"' prints?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Please see edits. I placed values in everything except latitude.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Why doesn't the echo "t" work?

Comment: Can you post the result of `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: I tested the `form` as it is here, and it works. Do the `var_dump($_POST);` test.

Comment: working fine on my side. can u check the action? `validate2.php` is it right? i am using same file for form and php code. and its working fine

Comment: Test it in a single file with `action=""` and `var_dump($_POST);` at the end

Comment: @Hackerman Please see updated edit with the results of var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Please see updated edit with the results of var_dump($_POST)

Comment: change `if ($latitude  == NULL) {` with `if (empty($latitude)) {`

Comment: @devpro Yes, the action is okay. Did your "echo t" statement work?

Comment: yes, its working. also try with `if ($latitude == NULL) { with if (empty($latitude)) {`

Comment: its showing `wtq`

Comment: your latidute is equal to `""` empty, you can't check it with NULL

Comment: Did you notice that `submit` is missing in your output of `var_dump($_POST)` ??

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I just did. Why is that so?

Comment: Seems a server or PHP konfiugration bug or so. Here all works fine. So it isnt the code itself. some other magical stuff on your server.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thanks, so there's no way for me to fix it?

Comment: Not in PHP currently. Test the code on another server. Or just test for `["latitude"]` is set in the first place, you dont need to check for `submit`, maybe take a hidden input and take that for check. ..... cant tell more, not enuff infos

Comment: Did you 'click' the button or do you hit 'enter' ??--- foragt that :) imout

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions It doesn't work when I hit enter but it does work when i click the button. Thanks. Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Why check for a 'submit' post variable when you're working with latitude?

```
if(isset($_POST['latitude']))
{
     echo "t";
     $latitude=$_POST['latitude'];
}
else
{
     echo "Please insert a latitude . <br>";
     $error = $error + 1;
}
```

Also there is no need for a name on the submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Because I'll be adding more validations within the if statement. My main question isn't about the validation of latitude but why doesn't 'echo t' work?

Comment: Previous comment says all, in your post dump there is no submit post variable, that's why I wouldn't check for it.  You have latitude, longitude, wave_type, wave_value, file.  Just do your if isset statement on variables that actually get set.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--form code start-->
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['req']))
{
    echo "Please enter any input";
}
?>
<form action="validate2.php" method="POST">
    Latitude: <input type='text' name='latitude'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<!--validate2.php code start-->
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    if ($latitude  == NULL)
    {   
        header("Location:frm.php?req=error");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Your input Text is: ".$latitude;      
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have your form rendering messed up, this works:

```
echo "<h1> Seismic Recording </h1>";
echo "<div>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";

echo "Latitude: <input type='text' name='latitude'>";
echo "Longitude: <input type='text' name='longitude'd>";
echo 'Wave Type: <select id="wave_type" name="wave_type">';
echo '<option selected value="s">S</option>';
  echo '<option value="p">P</option>';
  echo '<option value="surface_wave">Surface Wave</option>';
echo "</select>";
echo "Wave Value: <input type='text' name='wave_value' d>";
echo 'Upload CSV File: <input type="file" name="file">';
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";

if(isset($_POST)){
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   echo "Submit is alive!!";
  }
}
```

In order to avoid this kind of issues, remember that you can just write plain html, on this way:

```
<?php
  //Mi php code blablabla
?>
/* My html code */
<h1>Wonderful day, isn't it?<h1>

<?php
  //Another php tasks and etc
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--Second Method--> 
<!--form code start-->
<form action="validate2.php" method="POST">
    Latitude: <input type='text' name='latitude'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<!--validate2.php code start-->
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
    if ($latitude  == NULL)
    {   
        echo '<script>alert("Please enter any input");
        window.location.href="frm.php";</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Your input Text is: ".$latitude;      
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$curl_connection = 
  curl_init('http://www.domainname.com/target_url.php');
```

link:-http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-submit.html